# Probability of a baseball team winning next 2 games

Tags: probability

Given their previous performance, the probability of a particular baseball team winning any given game is 4/5.
The probability that the team will win their next 2 games is...

I'm confused on how to start this question. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Assume that the probability of the team winning the next 2 games are independent of each other. Then Probability they win both = (4/5) * (4/5) = 16/25.

It is important to note that this only works if the probability of winning the next 2 games are independent of each other, although this is probably assumed in the question. We can take this to be implied by the wording of the question ('probability of winning any given game = 4/5' in a way only makes sense if probability of winning any given game is independent of anything else including results of other games).

Answer (score 1):

Probability of a particular baseball team winning any given game is 4/5.
Probability that the team will win their next 2 games is probability of winning 1st match $*$ probability of winning 2nd match.

$$P = (4/5) * (4/5)$$
$$P = 16/25$$